# return a part of a line / catch a group

Tags: sed

I have a string

```
[something] aa-xy56/efgertg
```

I know `aa-` and I want `aa-xy56` returned (== everything up to `/` excluded)

This is what should match the string up to '/' :

```
 echo [something] aa-xy56/wegrt | sed -n '/(aa\-[A-Za-z0-9]*)\/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*\(aa-[A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: ok, and do you know how to match the '] ' parenthesis and whitespace in front?

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
sed 's/.*\(aa-[^/]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's?.*\(aa-[A-Za-z0-9]*\)/.*?\1?p'
```